# London Fare Zones spatial data

Tags: geospatial, uk, public-transport

Does anyone know if the London Fare Zones are available as a spatial data set?

An example of a spatial data set would be:

- Shapefile
- KML
- GeoJSON

Comment: relevant? https://www.whatdotheyknow.com/request/mapping_table_london_fare_zones

Comment: @philshem thanks - I guess it doesn't really exist then. So if I created zones based on stations that would be as good as any data set available?

Comment: I did find this which might be similar https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?dg=feature&msa=0&mid=1eIjWEQyO-PchgJUttxBBkYqvPxE&ll=51.49280340511744%2C-0.17372399999999288&z=10

Comment: yes, it seems that the shapes of fare zones can be generated as "topographical contour" between the points

Answer (score 2):

It's not great but you could probably extract the data from the SVG

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/London_Underground_Overground_DLR_Crossrail_map_zone.svg

```
<g id="zone6">
    <title>Fare zone 6</title>
    <path fill="#eee" d="
    M 534,151
    H 625 q 7.5,0 13.5,-4.5
    l 400,-300
    H 1400
    l 72,96 q 6,8 16,8
    H 1700 q 7.5,0 13.5,-4.5
    l 100,-75
    H 2320
    V 60 a 20,20 0 0,0 20,20
    H 2600 V 1500
    H -50 V 750
    H 40 a 20,20 0 0,0 20,-20
    V 440 a 20,20 0 0,0 -20,-20
    H -50
    V 165
    H 380 c 20,0 20,-14 40,-14
    z"/>
    <g class="zonefw b mid">
        <text x="435" y="185">6</text>
        <text x="1440" y="-55">6</text>
        <text x="1800" y="-55">6</text>
        <text x="2290" y="148">6</text>
        <text x="70" y="1030">6</text>
        <text x="90" y="675">6</text>
        <text x="90" y="250">6</text>
    </g>
</g>
```

There seem to be a lot of exceptions, though, since some stations are in 2 fare zones.

---

There are some tools for converting SVG to GIS formats, although I think it's not a task for a beginner. See [for example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/161815/112869).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After some searching I found this data set which can be downloaded as a KML file. It is made from contouring stations of a shared zone and can be found [here.](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?dg=feature&msa=0&mid=1eIjWEQyO-PchgJUttxBBkYqvPxE&ll=51.49280340511744%2C-0.17372399999999288&z=10)

It would appear that a data set from Transport for London does not exist so this may be the closest representation.